# How to perform serialization in micronaut

Tags: grails, serialization, groovy, marshalling, micronaut

When i was using grails for microservices API response can be defined using `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller`
And now i have shifted to micronaut but there is not marshaller support in micronaut how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

You simply use Jackson annotations on any POJO/POGO

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations